# Angular 2 - Defining Inputs in Abstract (Parent) Component

Tags: angular

We are using custom components in our new Angular 2 app, and recently wanted to extract some parts in a parent component, which will be then extended from the child components. But we have some problems with the @Input() attributes.

When we define their Inputs in parent component, the app works as expected with "ng serve" (in development mode). But when we build the app with "ng build --prod", the compiler complains about these inputs (label is our input in this example) as if they are not a part of child component's declaration. It looks like this:

```
<jb-input class="col-md-6"
          name="name"
          [label]="'surname'"
          ngModel
          required>
</jb-input>
```

Child Component decleration:

```
export class JbInputComponent extends JbFormBasicComponent implements OnInit {

  ...
```

Parent Component decleration:

```
@Injectable()
export default abstract class JbFormBasicComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {

  @Input() label: string;
  ...
```

When we also define our input in child component, it works. But is there a better way of achieving this without defining our inputs in both places?

- Here we have our parent-child relation just in the component class level. The parent does not need to have its own selector/template.

UPDATE:

We can also define those inputs in Component declerations of children. So:

```
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: '..',
  templateUrl: '..',
  inputs: ['label', ..]
})
export class JbInputComponent extends JbFormBasicComponent implements OnInit {
..
```

Another option is: defining parent also as a Component:

```
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  template: ''
})
export class JbFormBasicComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {
..
```

So the input & output fields will be visible for children, without defining them again in each child. But now this Component must also be declared in app.module, since it is also a Component now. In this way parent does not need to have an @Injectable annotation.

But we still do not know which way we should take.. Angular Documentation is also like a joke.

Comment: I don't have much idea for angular cli. But just a hint: When something works on development and doesn't work in production it's because some production plugins are messing up the code.

As a side note, I feel kind of weird that you are decorating an abstract component with @injectable

Comment: We have also thoughts about those plugins (minifier etc.). Other thing: without @injectable does not work at all.. i also dont know why.. This is the error we see in the console: Can't resolve all parameters for "ourChildComponent": (?).

Comment: You could try to run on development with same plugins as production... the built may take longer, but most likely you'll find out that it doesn't work... then start removing plugins one by one, until you find out the one that mess it up.

Regarding injectable it's a decorator only used to mark a class as available for DI; Which doesn't make much sense for a component and even less for an abstract class. But I might be missing something.